# Count unique rows GROUP(ed) BY different columns than used in DISTINCT ON

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, distinct-on

I'm sure this has been asked over and over, but I can't quite find a simple example that I can fully grok.

I'm trying to deduplicate (do a `DISTINCT ON`) by one column and `COUNT` records `GROUPed By` columns that differ from the column used to deduplicate, but without introducing subqueries.

Let's say I have a table with the following information:

| order_num | date | region | timestamp_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-09-01 | Murica | 2021-09-**02**T19:00:01Z |
| 001 | 2021-09-01 | Murica | 2021-09-**03**T19:00:01Z |
| 002 | 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2021-09-02T19:00:01Z |
| 003 | 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2021-09-03T19:00:01Z |
| 004 | 2021-09-02 | Yurop | 2021-09-03T19:00:01Z |

I would like to first get unique records with different `order_num` (keeping the most recently updated) ones **AND** then count groups or orders by `date` and `region`.

- De-duplicate (gets rid of the oldest `order_num='001A'`):

  | order_num | date | region | timestamp_updated |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 001 | 2021-09-01 | Murica | 2021-09-**03**T19:00:01Z |
  | 002 | 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2021-09-02T19:00:01Z |
  | 003 | 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2021-09-03T19:00:01Z |
  | 004 | 2021-09-02 | Yurop | 2021-09-03T19:00:01Z |
- Then group by and count:

  | date | region | count |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 2021-09-01 | Murica | 1 |
  | 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2 |
  | 2021-09-02 | Yurop | 1 |

I know how to do those two things separately (`distinct on(order_num)` + `order by timestamp_updated desc`) to deduplicate and then `select count(*)` + `group by date, region` ) And even together with subqueries. But I'd like to try to avoid subqueries as much as possible and here's where window functions (seem) to come in handy and I don't know <strike>much</strike> anything about those.

The closest thing I've been able to get are groups, but they show one record by each `order_num`. The records are correct, but they are duplicated:

```
select distinct on (order_num) date, region, count(1)over (
    partition by order_num
)
from orders_table
order by order_num, timestamp_updated desc;
```

That query ^^ shows:

| date | region | count |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-01 | Murica | 1 | I *think* this is the first 001 |
| 2021-09-01 | Murica | 1 | I *think* this is the second 001 |
| 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2 | I *think* this is the first Yurop: 002 |
| 2021-09-01 | Yurop | 2 | I *think* this is the second Yurop: 003 |
| 2021-09-02 | Yurop | 1 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the max `timestamp_updated` per `order_num, date, region` and then aggregate again to get the counts per `date, region` using `window function`

```
select distinct 
       date, 
       region, 
       count(max(timestamp_updated)) over (partition by date, region) as counts 
from t
group by order_num, date, region;
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vvQ67GfZmZm7KkwTFUsFee/1)

Comment: ah, this is working great! Thank you!! :)